# issues with freeglut on mac os snow leopard (it builds fine via macports)

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw, freeglut

im on mac os snow leopard gcc 4.5.4 | gcc 4.2.1, trying to build the tutorials http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

one needs to build dir glsdk first. I install freeglut (prerequisite) via macports freeglut @2.8.0_1 (active) and manually copy and paste its lib and include folders in dir glsdk so that 
ls ..../Tutorial_0_3_8/glsdk/freeglut ->  include lib
(I couldn't build the freeglut provided that's why I replace it with the one from macports)

after fixing many errors (mostly due to legacy snippets included) I'm testing the build in Test dir and when I try to run the generated executable ./TestD, I get:

> X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
>         Major opcode of failed request:  34 (X_UngrabKey)
>         Serial number of failed request:  28
>         Current serial number in output stream:  28

what's this? a bit of search suggests this is a driver's problem(?)..
when I use glut with other gl code it runs just fine

Comment: I would recommend compiling with options `-L/opt/local/lib -I/opt/local/include`, not copying files to current directory.

Comment: it doesn't help though, I get the same error

Comment: I am going over these tutorials. I am adapting them using Xcode and FLGW3. In case it is of help to anybody, I have the first two chapters here: https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/gltut-flgw

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez good job with the port to GLFW!

Answer (score 2):

my X11 is broken** and this seems to be the problem.
since it's tricky to build this set of tutorials, I repeat the steps I followed for anyone facing similar trouble

1. get the source https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/downloads, untar and fill in the gaps so that you have Tutorial_0_3_8 instead of Tutorial 0 3 8
2. in glsdk directory, comment out `--"freeglut/freeglut.lua`, in premake4.lua
3. in glsdk directory, `./premake gmake` and then `make config=release`
4. in framework directory, framework.cpp, manually replace macros `LOCAL_FILE_DIR` & `GLOBAL_FILE_DIR` with "./data/" `"./data/"` & `"../data/"` respectively and comment out `#include "directories.h"`
5. build all the tutorials in a single step from root or those that you need, e.g. in Test directory put the right paths to include for freeglut headers and link with the: 
   in Test.make replace `-I../glsdk/glutil/include` and `-L../glsdk/glutil/lib` with paths from freeglut build via macports. Also in the same makefile link with `-lglut` instead of `-lfreeglut`

**`dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_DGifGetLine
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libGIF.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO`

Comment: I followed the steps in this answer, but I still get the `X Error of failed request: BadRequest` error you posted in your question. Can you think of any other step you did?