# Can't set GL flags with GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Trying to set one or more of the following OpenGL flags:

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

makes `glfwOpenWindow` fail. Why is this the case?

> [Edit] It seems to work with MAJOR=3 and MINOR=2, but the Notebook the
>   code runs on (MacBook Retina Mid2012) is possible to run up to OpenGL
>   4.1 (Intel HD 4000 has OpenGL 4.0, Nvidia GT 650M has 4.1). [/Edit]

Also, while it might be unrelated, `glfwGetGLVersion` returns `0` for all three parameters.

Full example code below:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(!glfwInit()) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE, GL_TRUE);
    //glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    //glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    //glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    {
        int *major = new int, *minor = new int, *rev = new int;
        glfwGetGLVersion(major, minor, rev);
        std::cout << *major << " " << *minor << " " << *rev << std::endl;
        delete major;
        delete minor;
        delete rev;
    }

    if(!glfwOpenWindow(512,512,
                       8,8,8,
                       8,24,8,
                       GLFW_WINDOW)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
            // APPLICATION EXITS HERE IF ONE OF THE FLAGS ARE SET.
    }

    while (glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED)) {   
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that MacBook running OSX or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964416/mac-os-10-8-supports-glsl-3-30

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a MacBook, you're probably running OSX. And while your graphics card has the *ability* to support OpenGL 4.x, *OSX* only supports OpenGL 3.2.

Comment: Just adding that this *will* work on 10.9, provided your GPU is capable of OpenGL 3.3, as Apple has added support for that version.